# Custom on page Login form to make use of spring login authentication

Tags: java, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I have earlier used spring's default login form to authenticate users. Now I am trying to create a login form inside a div on my home page like on most websites. And value for `action` tag is equal to `/login` which I guess is the default url for spring login authentication. But I am getting a `404 Requested resource is not available`. How can I use a custom form to implement a spring login authentication? Below is my code.

login form:

```
       <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login" method="POST">
            <div class="w100" style=""></div>
            <div class="w100 formHeading">
                <fmt:message key="login"></fmt:message>
            </div>
            <div class="w100">
                <label for="username">Username</label> 
                <input type="text"
                    id="username" name="username" /> 
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
                <div class="w100">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
                </div>
        </form>
```

security configuration:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"  />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="denyAll" />

    <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/" />
    <security:csrf disabled="true" />
</security:http>
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"></security:global-method-security>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following applies to **version 3.x.x** of Spring Security (4.x.x is different, thanks to @Ritesh for pointing it out):

The default URL to process the login form data is `/j_spring_security_check` (this is different from "login page"). So:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check" method="POST">
```

Also note that with defaults, the input fields should be named `j_username` and `j_password`.

Comment: This is not the case (at least in newer versions). See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-form. The login url can be same as the form action (getting the form is GET and submit is POST) and username and password parameter names are default names. (But you could be right because it is not clear which spring security version OP is using)

Comment: @Ritesh They changed it in 4.0.0, I didn't know, thanks. Updated answer.